# how to reload or refresh a tab's content base on actions in vaadin

Tags: java, tabs, actionlistener, vaadin

The content of the tab is formed and displayed when the application is loaded. Later the content of the tab may be changed by other actions. I want to show the newer content after each action. And each time when I click the tab sheet, the content should be refresh/updated. But I failed.

```
    //the content of the tab from the "reprintsTab" class
    //in the "reprintsTab" it query data from database and print out
    //later I update the data in the database from somewhere else, and I want the tab shows the new content
    //I want to click the tab sheet to reload the "reprintTab" class and print out the new content

    //here is what I did:

    public TabSheet sheet;

    //add tab and add the content from "reprintTab" into this tab
    sheet.addTab(new reprintsTab());

    //add the listener 
    sheet.addListener(new TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void selectedTabChange(SelectedTabChangeEvent event) {

        //I know it does not work, because it only reload the class. but not put the content under the tab I want
        new reprintsTab();

        }
    });
```

What should I do? please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TabSheet.replaceComponent](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html#replaceComponent%28com.vaadin.ui.Component,%20com.vaadin.ui.Component%29) method to do this:

```
//Field to store current component
private reprintsTab currentComponent; 

//during initialization
currentComponent = new reprintsTab();
sheet.addTab(currentComponent);

sheet.addListener(new TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void selectedTabChange(SelectedTabChangeEvent event) {
        reprintsTab newComponent = new reprintsTab();
        sheet.replaceComponent(currentComponent, newComponent);
        currentComponent = newComponent;
    }
});
```

Also, you might want to reload this tab only when it's shown:

```
sheet.addListener(new TabSheet.SelectedTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectedTabChange(SelectedTabChangeEvent event) {
            if (event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab() == currentComponent) {
                //here goes the code
            }
        }
});
```

This should work for you, but I would suggest a cleaner approach: implement `reprintsTab` as a container for components, create method `reload` or `buildInterface` method to refresh its' state, so you can just call:

```
currentComponent.reload();
```

when you need to update interface.

Also, I hope `reprintsTab` is just an example name, java class names starting with lowercase letter look ugly.